# How can I extend Android Universal Image Loader to download 2 or more files?

Tags: android, css, svg, universal-image-loader

I want to display some SVG-Images from web with UIL. So I implemented my own `ImageDecoder` to decode the svgs. Everything's working fine so far.

But unfortunatly the svg is showing only a black screen, because the css is not embeded. So I need to download the css, too. How can I achieve this?

I know that i have to extend the `ImageDownloader` class and must implement the getStream()-Method. But how exactly do I have to implement the method?

Thank's for your help!

Best Regards,

Robin

Answer (score 1):

`getStream()` is called once and returns single `InputStream`. So I don't think overriding of `ImageDownloader` is a solution.
I think you should download your css file in `ImageDecoder` but I don't know how you want to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to show the SVG, which is formatted with css. So I need the SVG and corresponding CSS in the same directory. What do you think is the best solution for this?

Comment: I think you can download CSS after SVG is downloaded (in `ImageDecoder`).